# aioodbc question mark in sql server error

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, aiohttp

I use aioodbc for connect to SQL Server for aiohttp. I was written 2 functions in python3:

```
async with aioodbc.create_pool(dsn=dsn, loop=loop, autocommit=True) as pool:
    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(query)
            val = await cur.fetchall()

async def main(request):
    args = request.GET
    ses = request.cookies.get('sess')
    data = []
    try:
        data = await sqlQuery('dbo.sp_roles'+ " " + ses )
   except Exception as e:
        return web.Response(text = dumps({'message':str(e)}), status = 500)) 
   return web.Response(text = dumps(data))
```

and stored procedure in SQL Server. In the procedure, I use `raiserror` with cyrillic characters like this:

```
RAISERROR('пользователь не найден',16, 1)
```

and when I catch `Exception as e` in python function its looks like

```
������������ �� ������
```

Data with cyrillic characters in `SELECT` returns right. It's happened only when I raiserror. How can I get right error message in python?

Comment: Have you tried `RAISERROR(N'пользователь не найден',16,1)`? (i.e. prefixing the string with **N** to indicate that it's unicode)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help

Comment: Try to add encoding (`cp1251` for Ru) in the top of the `.py` file where you rise\catch error. Mb it will help

Comment: No, It doesn't help too

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The reason was pyodbc old version. If you have the same error, you are must uninstall pyodbc `pip uninstall pyodbc` and install it (new version) again `pip install pyodbc`